# Using a function on all elements of a list and awaiting their promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, promise

Basically what I'm trying to do is, say I have a function, `something()` that returns a promise and a whole lot of values that I would like to resolve

```
let values = ['123', '456', '789']
```

How can I resolve all of them while avoiding doing something like this

```
let temp = [];
let newValue;

for(let x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
    newValue = await something(values[x]);
    temp.push(newValue);
}
```

Reason is because I don't want to have to await for the promises to be resolved before moving onto the next loop. Is there any way I can just await all at once? and have them be in a list? Or would the method be no different than awaiting them all in order using the `for` loop.

Comment: Do you care if `temp` is populated in the same order as the values are in `values`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The order doesn't matter for me

Comment: Build a list of promises `temp.push(something(values[x]));` later `let values = await Promise.all(temp);`.

Comment: Nice thing about my answer is it maintains the order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
function something(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // to show what happens when they're resolved out of order
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 1000 - parseInt(value));
  });
}

// wrap `await` statement in an anonymous async function
(async function() {
  let values = ['123', '456', '789'];
  let temp = await Promise.all(values.map(something));

  console.log(temp);
})();
```

Comment: Just what I needed!